# How to avoid dozer mapping blank strings in spring boot java app?

Tags: java, spring, dozer

Consider the following xml dozer bean mapping below:

```xml
   <mapping map-null="false" map-empty-string="false">
        <class-a>com.example.howtodoinjava.dozer.models.Student</class-a>
        <class-b>com.example.howtodoinjava.dozer.models.StudentVO</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>batch</a>
            <b>batchName</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>address</a>
            <b>homeAddress</b>
        </field>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

In the above dozer xml mapping, how to avoid map **batch** to **batchName** when batch is ***blank*** ("  ")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dozer documentation is your friend:
https://dozermapper.github.io/gitbook/documentation/xmlConfiguration.html

Add `trim-strings="true"` to the mapping.

During the mapping of the field, String.trim() will be called on the source field value to "convert" it to the destination.  This in combination with the skip empty strings already in the mapping perform as desired.

Comment: I already have ```map-empty-string="false"``` option in the request as you can see in my original question. but the issue here is when  a field has blank (empty string + spaces) it is mapping which I donot want.

Comment: Ah, yeah, missed that detail.   Answer updated.